# Can I use complex analysis to solve a vector calculus problem?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

This is a question from a non-mathematician, so excuse me if I use a more plain language.
Why can't I use complex analysis methods to solve a problem in vector calculus in 2 dimensions?
Say we are in 2 dimensions; we have unit vectors $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ at the $x$ and $y$ axis respectively. If we replace the $\hat{j}$ with $\hat{i}$ and we make the y axis the imaginary axis, then what is the difference between solving a problem with complex analysis methods and solving it with vector calculus methods?

**Edit:** **I know that there** ***should*** **a difference but I do not know what it is.**

Comment: Basically differentiate in complex analysis is not the same than differentiate in $R^2$, you have to add the Cauchy Rieman relations

Comment: But what causes that difference? I know that there SHOULD be a difference, but I do not know what is the fundamental reason of why they are not the same things.

Comment: The fundamental reason why there is a difference is that multiplication of complex numbers makes sense, whereas multiplication of points of the $xy$-plane does not. This leads to a definition for complex differentiability analogous to that of differentiability for a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, which is not possible if you think of $\mathbb C$ as simply $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be complex numbers.  Let $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ be the vector analogues of $z_1$ and $z_2$.  Note that $\bar z_1z_2= (\vec r_1\cdot \vec r_2)+i(\vec r_1\times \vec r_2)\cdot \hat z$.  So, we see that complex multiplication implicates both the inner product and the cross product of the vector analogues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a direct correspondence between vector fields on the 2d plane and complex functions.  Hence, problems that can be described as integrals of the former (in particular, line integrals of vector fields) can be described as contour integrals in complex analysis instead.

As has been said, the notion of differentiation is different.  In particular, those vector fields whose divergence and curl are zero correspond to complex functions that are complex differentiable.  There is, however, a direct correspondence between $\nabla$ in vector calculus and $\partial/\partial \bar z$.

Comment: So is there any restriction to this or can we apply complex methods to any vector problem in 2d plane?

Comment: There is no restriction.

Comment: Muphrid, what is the direct correspondence please?

Answer (score 2):

**Some** two-dimensional vector calculus problems can be solved using complex methods.  It really depends on the problem.  Some can easily be translated into the language of complex analysis, others not so easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please add to your answer what factor define whether or not this can be used in a problem?

Comment: Is it a matter of how easy it is to do or if its possible to do?